# Creating a Subversion branch

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a Subversion repository (running SVN 1.6.6) on an [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) Linux server, and I'm trying to create a branch using the [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) GUI; However, I get an error back:

> COPY c:\work\repositoryWorkingcopy\ to http://svnserver/svn/repository/Oct13, Revision HEAD
>
> Error
>   '/svn/repository/!svn/bc/234/branches'
>   path not found

I logged into my Linux box to see if the "branches" folder was NOT available. However, I could see that /var/svn/repository/branches existed.

So, what's the problem and how do I fix it?

I tried the following command (as per http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-sect-2.1) as well as from the command line and got a similar error:

```
c:\workingcopy> svn copy http://reposerver/svn/repository/ http://reposerver/svn/repository/branches/BFI_Oct13/ -m "Creating a branch"
```

> svn: '/svn/repository/!svn/bc/235/branches' path not found

What should I do?

Also, `svn info` on the main directory of the working copy gives the following information.

```
Path: .
URL: http://reposerver/svn/myrepository
Repository Root: http://reposerver/svn/myrepository
Repository UUID: 7a31d3c0-b288-4695-aecd-3f9dda2861ab
Revision: 235
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: anjan
Last Changed Rev: 235
Last Changed Date: 2010-10-13 20:39:31 +0530 (Wed, 13 Oct 2010)
```

Comment: Verify your SVN server has rear/write permission on the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say:

> I logged into my Linux box to see if the "branches" folder was NOT available. However, I could see that /var/svn/repository/branches existed.

Do you mean that the actual directory exists in the filesystem (which will do you absolutely no good), or that it exists in the repository?

Possible fix:

```
$ svn mkdir http://reposerver/svn/repository/branches
$ svn copy http://reposerver/svn/repository/ http://reposerver/svn/repository/branches/BFI_`date +%b%d`/ -m "Creating a branch"
```

Comment: hi Wrikken, thanks. I meant that the actual directory exists in the fs. Will try your suggestion and see how it goes.

Comment: that kinda did the trick. BUT holy cow, when I tried to update my "trunk" working copy, I got a new folder called branches/Oct13 with a full copy of my trunk directory structure. Now, how do I get rid of this directory. pls. help --- we're about to make a release soon and this new directory at the root of the "TRUNK" working copy is going to break the build. thank you.

Comment: c:\new_workingCopy>svn mkdir --parents http://repoServer/svn/myrepository/branches -m
 "creating branch"

Committed revision 236.

c:\new_workingCopy>svn copy http://repoServer/svn/myrepository/ http://reposerver/svn/myrepository/branches/BFI_Oct13/ -m "Creating a branch"

Committed revision 237.

Comment: There are no 'special' branches in subversion: `branches` is just a directory. Normally, in the root of an svn repo you'd create a `trunk` and `branches` folder yourself after creation. If you didn't at the start, and just added the project directly to the 'root' / `/` of the repo, it will be a subfolder indeed. Possible workaround is to create a folder `trunk` now, and move the current content of the root sans branches dir into that location. If you need the files to stay at the current location, you'll either have to live with the branches subfolder, or forget about branching altogether.

Comment: in the above command there is a h t t p : / / missing because of some filtering by the edit control.

Comment: Wrikken : thanks. I understand what happened now. How do I get rid of the branches/Oct13 directory tree ? I will attempt the branching a lil later. First I need to undo what I did earlier. thank you.

Comment: that worked. thank you. Now, after creating a "trunk" folder, how do I move the current content of the "root sans branches dir" to the "trunk" folder ? thanks again.

Comment: Just perform a `svn mv`, see `svn help mv` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you'll want to branch on the server, make your changes in the branch, and check those changes in.

So, the first step is to create the branch, which is just a copy command. In TortoiseSVN, you need the URL to (presumably) the trunk, and you'll need to define the URL of the branch. In a more standard repository setup, the trunk might be http://svnserver/svn/repository/trunk and your branch might be http://svnserver/svn/repository/branches/Oct13.

Then, you'll want to switch your working copy to the branch. You should have the option to do so without losing your local changes.

Finally, you would check your changes in, and they should go to the branch from there.

I'm more accustomed to the command-line interface for SVN, but I have used TortoiseSVN. It's been a while, though, so leave a comment if you still have trouble or this doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks. pls. see update. I tried the command line instruction as well, in vain.

Comment: @anjanb Could you post the output of <code>svn info</code> while in your main working directory?

Comment: Path: .
URL: http://reposerver/svn/myrepository
Repository Root: http://reposerver/svn/myrepository
Repository UUID: 7a31d3c0-b288-4695-aecd-3f9dda2861ab
Revision: 235
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: anjan
Last Changed Rev: 235
Last Changed Date: 2010-10-13 20:39:31 +0530 (Wed, 13 Oct 2010)