# creating a subversion branch after creating project at repository root

Tags: linux, svn, branch, branching-and-merging

Pls. see [Creating a Subversion branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925329/creating-a-subversion-branch). I created a repository with a URL http://reposerver/svn/repository/ and checked out a working copy and started adding files to the root instead of doing it into the trunk folder.

Now, we need to create a branch except we don't have a "trunk" folder. From the above link, user "Wrikken" suggested that we "Possible workaround is to create a folder trunk now, and move the current content of the root sans branches dir into that location. "

Now, we don't know how to do "move the current content of the root sans branches dir into that location". What command should we use to do the same ?

When we do ls -la of /var/svn/repository, here's what we see

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data subversion 4096 2010-12-28 18:20 conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data   4096 2010-12-28 18:23 dav
drwxr-sr-x 6 www-data subversion 4096 2010-12-28 18:31 db
-r--r--r-- 1 www-data subversion    2 2010-12-28 18:20 format
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data subversion 4096 2010-12-28 18:20 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data subversion 4096 2010-12-28 18:20 locks
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data subversion  229 2010-12-28 18:20 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         95 2010-12-28 18:41 svn-commit.tmp
```

TL DR : We need to create a branch and our repository does NOT have "trunk" and "branches" 
so what commands do we need to use to move existing repository content to a trunk directory ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following commands in the root of a working copy of the repository (`ls` should output the contents of your repository, not the files and directories quoted in the question).

```
svn mkdir trunk
svn mv `ls | egrep -v '^branches$` trunk
svn ci -m 'Create trunk dir and move trunk contents into it.'
```

`egrep -v '^branches$` matches everything except `branches`. The `mv` command will be clever enough to *not* try move `trunk` into itself, although it will yell at you with an error you can safely ignore.

Comment: You should probably mentation that this must be executed in the directory of a working copy, not the location of the repository in the file system anjanb is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subversion client of your choice. It should have a move operation. (Unlike CVS, moving a file/directory in subversion retains the history of the moved file/directory.)

For example, if your are using the Tortoise SVN client, here's the relevant part of the help file:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html